# How does plasma density influence ionization energy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, ionization-energy

I'm going over a book on plasma spectroscopy which plots the partition function for different elements, temperatures, and lowering of ionization energy. However I struggle to replicate the results.

The partition function  of element $a$ in charge state $z$ is given as
$$u_a^z(T) = \sum_{i=1}^{i=n^*} g_{a,i}^z \exp\left[-\frac{E_{a,i}^z}{k_BT}\right]$$
where $i=1$ denotes the ground state and $i=n^*$ the highest level which is still bound. $g_{a,i}^z$ is the statistical weight of level $i$ and $E_{a,i}^z$ the corresponding energy level.

To estimate $n^*$ the book states to calculate the lowering of the ionization energy with *Unsöld*'s formula
$$\Delta E_z^\text{ion}=3e^2(z+1)^{2/3}\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}n_e\right)^{1/3}$$
where $n_e$ is the electron density.
For iron there is an example stated as
$\Delta_\text{Fe0}=0.12-0.28\,\mathrm{eV}$
with an electron density of
$0.5-7\cdot10^{16}\,\mathrm{cm^{-3}}$.

Furthermore the partition function is depicted for iron and nitrogen as
[image: Example from the book]
which I managed to replicate somewhat (the results seem too low overall), with the exception of the curves for different lowering of ionization energy. In my graph, the orange and green line are almost identical.
[image: My replication]

1. I'm not sure hot to apply the lowering of ionization energy to $n^*$. Do I toss all energy levels where
   $E_{a,i}^z > E_{z,\max}^\text{ion}-\Delta E_z^\text{ion}$
   with
   $E_{z,\max}^\text{ion}$
   being the ionization energy? I take all values from the [NIST Atomic Spectra Database](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl?de=0&spectrum=fe+i&units=1&format=0&output=0&page_size=15&multiplet_ordered=0&level_out=on&g_out=on&biblio=on&temp=0.8&submit=Retrieve+Data).
2. How do I calculate the lowering of ionization energy? Using $e$ as elementary charge, the units don't make sense and the result is multiple orders of magnitude off. Using $e$ as in Euler's number I still get something of a couple hundred eV.
3. Reading up on *Unsöld*'s formula ([paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1948ZA.....24..355U/abstract)) I can not find the same formula. From this paper it also doesn't become clear how to calculate the limit for the partition function.